# Ruby on Rails: Deleting multiple attachments in paperclip on updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-uploading

Paperclip's [document](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#deleting-an-attachment) says to set attribute to `nil` for deleting attachments (in my case - photos).

I want users to be able to edit their projects, and delete the photos they've attached. When they're ready to delete the photos, they'll click on the "Update" button, because they're editing the projects, not just removing photos. I'm using checkboxes because each project can contain multiple photos:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% @project.project_images.each do |pic| %> 
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, pic do |image_fields| %>
      <%= image_tag pic.photo.url(:thumb) %>
      <%= image_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

So, how do I use this to delete my photos within my update method in the controller?

Current:

```
def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)
      if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end       
    end
  end
end
```

You can see that I'm still creating new images into the database if user decides to do so.

In my log, I got this

```
"project_images_attributes"=>{
            "0"=>{"_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"25"}, 
            "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"26"}, 
            "2"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"27"}}
```

This shows that I did indeed checked off photo id's 26 and 27 to be deleted. So now, I just want to know how to pass this to my update method to be destroyed? I would have to loop through this, check the ids that have _destroy => 1 to it, and then add `nil` and then `save`?

And lastly, my project params (which includes `:_destroy`)

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    project_images_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :photo, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: Did you try to just pass as it is, because it seems that you are doing it in the correct way. You don't need to loop on it. Just in you project model you should have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images, allow_destroy: true`

Comment: @Deep oh you're a genius! that's what I forgot! viola! good call. Please make an answer so I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images, allow_destroy: true
```

in your `project.rb` and pass the parameters as it is, as it seems you are doing it the right way. The rest rails will handle to delete or create a new record. You don't need to loop on the `params[:photos]`.

Hope this helps.